# mongoid references_and_referenced_in_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, associations, mongoid

i have a strange problem. i am new to mongoid, so i am having trouble determining if it is me or mongoid at fault... presenting my code is perhaps the best explanation (minus the fields/validations/etc.)

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one  :profile, :class_name => "UserProfile"
  references_and_referenced_in_many :roles
end

class UserProfile
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :user
end

class Role
  include Mongoid::Document
  references_and_referenced_in_many :users
end
```

with the following associations, when i create instances of these objects like so...

```
user = User.new :username => 'username',
                :email => 'user@domain.com',
                :password => 'password'
user.build_profile  :first_name => 'John',
                    :last_name => 'Doe',
                    :birthday => Date.new(1980, 1, 1)
user.roles << Role.new(:name => 'Administrator')
user.save
```

...i can view this user with `User.first` or `user`

...i can view the profile with `User.first.profile` and `user.profile`

...i can view roles with `user.roles` but i **CANNOT** view them with `User.first.roles`.

another strange thing is `user.roles.count` AND `User.first.roles.count` both return 0, even though when i view `user.roles`, it returns `[#<Role _id: 4d8c0173e1607cdeae00002c, name: "Administrator", user_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('4d8c0173e1607cdeae00002a')]>]`. (`User.first.roles` returns an empty array)

this seems like a bug.

Answer (score 2):

use :autosave => true for the relational association

```
references_and_referenced_in_many :roles, :autosave => true
```

or you can explicitly save the `role` as

```
role = Role.new(:name => 'Administrator')
user.roles << role
role.save
user.save
```

This is due to changes in mongoid.2.0.0.rc.1 + listed [here](http://mongoid.org/docs/upgrading/).

> Relational associations no longer
>   autosave when the parent relation is
>   created. Previously a save on a new
>   document which had a references_many
>   or references_one association loaded
>   would save the relations on it's first
>   save. In order to get this
>   functionality back, an :autosave =>
>   true option must be provided to the
>   macro (This only applies to
>   references_many and references_one)

Comment: hmm.. still not saving. also user.roles is an array so there is no save method.

Comment: autosave should have worked, anyways i've edited the above answer.. hope it helps

Comment: yeah that works, but im curious why autosave isn't.  i was using rc7, so i upped to rc8 but with the same results... maybe autosave cannot be used with references_and_referenced_in_many, just references_many & references_one independently?

Comment: Do you have validation checks on role model? You might as well give a try by adding `:validates => false` besides autosave as it's working fine here using rc7.

Comment: try upgrading to **Mongoid 2.0.0**